# Notation for answer to basis of image (or kernel) problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a certain transformation T, I was suppose to find the basis for the image and kernel for T. My question is how you would state the answer to such a problem.

Is it okay to say that the **basis for the ker(T) = {[v1], [v2], ...}** and **basis for the im(T) = {[v1], [v2], ...}**?

Or do I have to specifically state that **basis for the ker(T) = spans{[v1], [v2], ...}** and likewise for the image?

Comment: The basis is $v_1,...,v_n$, not the span.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks copper.hat!